# function pointer to overloaded static member - to use as custom deleter in unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a class with static and overloaded member function.
I want to use one them as a custom deleter in a `unique_ptr`
there are lots of questions on this topic, none of them worked for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class A {
    public:
    static void release() {
        std::cout << "void released\n";
    }
    static void release(int*i) {
        std::cout << *i << " released\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(&A::release(int*))> ptr(&i, &A::release); // compiler error
    std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> ptr(&i, &A::release); // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

try it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/H14txk3sL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> ptr(&i, &A::release); 
//                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

This way, `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor will expect a specific type of a pointer, which will help the compiler resolve ambiguity.

---

This:

```
decltype(&A::release(int*))
```

is not a valid syntax. In order yo use `decltype(e)`, you'd have to write `decltype(&A::release)`, but this again would raise an ambiguity error, and so it would have to become:

```
decltype(static_cast<void(*)(int*)>(&A::release))
```

but that's a long-winded way of saying `void(*)(int*)`.

---

This:

```
std::function<void(int*)>
```

doesn't help in resolving ambiguity, becuase `std::functions`'s constructor is a template as well, which means the compiler again misses a context that would help it to choose one of the overloaded functions.